# 1С отчет: посчитать, сколько можно собрать комплектов

Tags: 1с

Есть два справочника: Номенклатура и Компьютеры. В первом хранятся товары, которые ставятся на приход, во втором товар, который собирается из товаров первого. Там указана табличная часть с Номенклатурой и количеством.
Есть вот такие комплектации для теста
Комп1: БлокПитания_1 - 1 шт, Процессор_1 - 2 шт.
Комп2: БлокПитания_2 - 2 шт, Процессор_2 - 1 шт.

Учет материалов ведется по Складам. Нужно сделать отчет, который бы показывал в разрезе складов, сколько можно собрать компов и какие.
Пока вот такой запрос

```
ВЫБРАТЬ
    Компьютеры.Наименование КАК Компьютер,
    КомпьютерыКомплектация.Номенклатура КАК Номенклатура,
    КомпьютерыКомплектация.Количество КАК Количество
ПОМЕСТИТЬ КомпьютерыВТ
ИЗ
    Справочник.Компьютеры.Комплектация КАК КомпьютерыКомплектация
        ЛЕВОЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ Справочник.Компьютеры КАК Компьютеры
        ПО (КомпьютерыКомплектация.Ссылка = Компьютеры.Ссылка)
;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
ВЫБРАТЬ
    ОстаткиМатериаловОстатки.Склад КАК Склад,
    КомпьютерыВТ.Номенклатура КАК Номенклатура,
    КомпьютерыВТ.Компьютер КАК Компьютер,
    ОстаткиМатериаловОстатки.КоличествоОстаток / КомпьютерыВТ.Количество КАК МожноСобрать
ИЗ
    КомпьютерыВТ КАК КомпьютерыВТ
        ЛЕВОЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ РегистрНакопления.ОстаткиМатериалов.Остатки(
                ,
                Материал В
                    (ВЫБРАТЬ
                        КомпьютерыВТ.Номенклатура КАК Номенклатура
                    ИЗ
                        КомпьютерыВТ КАК КомпьютерыВТ) ) КАК ОстаткиМатериаловОстатки
        ПО (КомпьютерыВТ.Номенклатура = ОстаткиМатериаловОстатки.Материал)
```

Проблема в следующем: на одном из складов нет блока питания_1, но есть процессор_1. По логике Комп1 не должен вообще показываться на этом складе, потому что из-за отсутствия одной комплектующей - нечего собрать.
Я не понимаю как нужно составить запрос, чтобы все выдавало верно. Явно как-то через МИНИМУМ сравнить результат частного в последнем поле, но как, честно, голову ломаю, не могу найти ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Первый запрос не требует ЛЕВОЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ доступ к Наименование можно получить через Ссылка; `КомпьютерыКомплектация.Ссылка.Наименование`

Допустим первым делом сделаем следующую выборку:

```
Склад, Комп, Номенклатура, Остаток, Остаток/Кво
```

тут нам нужно учесть две вещи:

1. Кво должно быть больше 0; `ГДЕ` в первом запросе
2. Остаток/Кво должно быть больше 1 если <1 то присвоим отрицательное -99; Это можно сделать с помощью `ВЫБОР КОГДА`

Далее сгруппируем и получим МИНИМУМ

```
Склад, Комп, МИНИМУМ(Остаток_Кво)
```

отрицательные (-99) отфильтруем `ГДЕ Остаток_Кво<>-99`

В итоге получим выборку вида

```
Склад, Комп, МИНИМУМ(Остаток_Кво) // Без -99 Можем Отсортировать !
```